# Sprite image having non-stop reflection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite-sheet

When i draw my sprite image on the canvas, and then it is suppose to reflect off the sides of the canvas. But after i draw some more sprite image onto the canvas, so of them when i hit the side of the canvas, it reflect non-stop making it a double image alone the side of the canvas. Here is the codes that make it change direction:

```
Fish.prototype.changeDirection = function () {
    speedXSign = this.speedX > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    speedYSign = this.speedY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    this.speedX = speedXSign * (1 + Math.random() * 2);
    this.speedY = speedYSign * (1 + Math.random() * 2);
};
```

My fiddle to check out the error after drawing multiple sprite image: http://jsfiddle.net/Bernard_9/8gTNk/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the fish hits the side, it's supposed to reflect. However, you are not checking for when the fish is hitting the side *while moving towards it*. For example, the fish is going right, and runs into the right wall. The speedX flips so he is travelling the other way. The next time the position is checked, he is still running into the wall (even though he's moving away from it), so the speedX is flipped again (now moving right again) so he runs into the wall, and the process repeats.

Fixed code (note the checks to speedX and speedY):

```
if ((this.xPos + this.frameWidth * this.frameScale / 2) >= canvas.width && this.speedX > 0 || 
    (this.xPos - this.frameWidth * this.frameScale / 2) <= 0 && this.speedX <= 0) {
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
}

this.yPos += this.speedY;
if ((this.yPos + this.frameHeight * this.frameScale / 2) >= canvas.height && this.speedY > 0 || 
    (this.yPos - this.frameHeight * this.frameScale / 2) <= 0 && this.speedY <= 0) {
    this.speedY = -this.speedY;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gTNk/8/

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example. Please reread my explanation. It hugs the wall because it's "colliding" with the side when it's going both towards and away from the wall.

Comment: Additionally, the "duplicate" fish is just the same fish flipping directions each frame really fast (left-right-left-right-left-right-left-right)